# error C2504: 'ostream_withassign' : base class undefined

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ by practicing with exercises from the book but I seem to have run into yet another problem. I know the ostream_withassign class is found in the iostream library and that is included but I still do not understand what I am missing in my code still. I tried std but that does not seem to work either. Any one able to please inform me on what I am missing please. Thanks in Advance!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Conios.h"


class ConsoleStream :public ostream_withassign, public Conios
{
protected:
    char X;
    char Y;


public:
    ConsoleStream(void);
    ConsoleStream(std::streambuf * Buffer);
    void SetX(char XX);
    void SetY(char YY);
    ConsoleStream &operator =(std::ostream &Out);
    ~ConsoleStream(void);
};
```

Comment: `ostream_withassign` is not a class contained in the C++ standard library. Also, what is the exact error message?

Comment: This question might be ironically timely, since assignment was disabled in C++03 but enabled (via `std::move`) in C++11. However, I wonder how an `ostream` derivative can take any `streambuf` and place its output at X,Y coordinates. This more likely requires a `streambuf` derivative, not `ostream`.

Comment: error C2504: 'ostream_withassign' : base class undefined

Answer (score 2):

Your book must be very old (in computing terms).  The `ostream_withassign` class was a nonstandard type available in "iostream.h" [back in Visual Studio 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277825%28v=VS.60%29.aspx). You should probably update your reference material and use something more modern as many, many things have changed in C++ since then (c. 1998).  (The most recent updates were [standardized this year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), in fact.)

Comment: Is there a replacement for this particular class in the revision? Or is there a way I can still take advantage of the old library?

Comment: @Kobo: The biggest advantage you can take of that old library is to replace it. No, really.

Comment: I am not certain what it can be replaced with. I have been trying to follow the exercises in the book in order to learn C++

Comment: I strongly suggest finding a different book that has up-to-date information. Maybe start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list